# Fire Autocomplete after input reaches 4 characters

Tags: 7, ajax

I am searching for a way, to fire the autocomplete event after 4 characters are in the input-field. What I am doing now is:

```
if(strlen($string) > 3) {
```

in my "page callback", but this is not the way I want it to work. Because now, the event is fireing, but only returns matches after 4 characters.
Is there a way to start the autocomplete only after the input?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I need to do the same thing ...

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/143720/30200

In short, you can defined a custom jquery event and associated it to your form_item. This event would fire only after a certain number of character