# Inline Javascript throws an error on drupal_add_js() within an AJAX callback

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, ajax

I am trying to get JavaScript to measure a text field and auto submit at a character limit for an Ajax callback to be validated against a Luhn Algorithm and errors out on failure to validate.

I found this code in [Firing ajax_callback on textfield after a minimum number of character](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/143715/firing-ajax-callback-on-textfield-after-a-minimum-number-of-character).

```javascript
// Trigger ajax event on myitem only after 5th character typed.
$('.myitem-class').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 5) {
    $(this).trigger('change');
  }
});
```

The JavaScript can allegedly be put inline in a wrapper like this to be used in an Ajax callback in a form. See [drupal_add_js within AJAX callback](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24299/drupal-add-js-within-ajax-callback).

```php
function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_add_js('Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.myFunction = function(ajax, response, status) {
    // …
    }',
    'inline'
  );

  return $form;
}
```

I got to run replacing `function(ajax, response, status)` with `function($, Drupal)`.

When I put in the code, it throws a PHP error at `).on(`. I wasn't able to get the inline wrapper recommended in [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x / JavaScript should be compatible with libraries other than jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/converting-drupal-6-modules-to-drupal-7/converting-6x-modules-to-7x#javascript_compatibility) to work because it fails seeing the `$` as a variable.

```javascript
(function ($) {
  // […]
}(jQuery));
```

Right now, I am stopped by syntax errors.

Does anyone know how to get this JavaScript code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick written code:

```
      <?php

      /**
        * Form.
        */
      function sample_luhn_form($form, &$form_state) {
        // I don't recommend inline js, prefer usual module js file, attach via $form['#attached'] or in module info file
        // Also I am use jQuery instead of $, but your shown (function ($) { }jQuery)); is preferred, I don't know why it's show errors, try inspect on dev.tools
        drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery(".luhn-nums").keydown(function() { if (jQuery(this).val().length >= 5) { jQuery(".luhn-check").mousedown(); } }); });', 'inline');


        // text field that should be checked for Luhn
        $form['luhn_nums'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Luhn numbers'),
          '#prefix' => '<div class="luhn-nums-wrapper">',
          '#suffix' => '</div>',
          '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('luhn-nums'),
          ),
        );
        // hidden ajax button
        $form['luhn_check'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'sample_luhn_form_ajax_submit',
            'wrapper' => 'luhn-nums-wrapper',
          ),
          '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('luhn-check', 'element-invisible', 'hidden'), // set class, that hide this ajax submit button or hide via CSS styles
          ),
        );

        // here goes another form elements
        // ...
        $form['submit'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Submit'),
        );
      }

      /**
       * Ajax callback function.
       */
      function sample_luhn_form_ajax_submit($form, &$form_state) {
        if (_sample_luhn_check($form_state['values']['luhn_nums'])) {
          // If luhn not passed
          form_set_message('luhn_nums', t('Luhn error, please fix numbers'));
        }
        // here you can alter luhn_nums textfield value
        return $form['luhn_nums'];
      }

      /**
       * Validate form.
       */
      function sample_luhn_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
        // Don't allow pass to submit untill luhn will passed
        if (_sample_luhn_check($form_state['values']['luhn_nums'])) {
          // If luhn not passed
          form_set_message('luhn_nums', t('Luhn error, please fix numbers'));
        }
      }

      /**
       * Form submit.
       */
      function sample_luhn_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
        // save data
      }

      /**
       * Private function that check luhn algorithms.
       */
      function _sample_luhn_check($nums) {
        $result = FALSE;

        // check numns by luhn algorithms
        // lot of code that alter $result

        return $result;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks - that is really close to what I had except for the " drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function ()  . . ." way to call JQuery.  I had seen that in some cases the function($) wrapper does not work, and this was going to be my next try.  I will try to cobble up this for the code and report back

Comment: usually it's not working, then you try use jQuery before jquery.js. I assume, you put this script at the footer.

Comment: Yes, Nikit, the code is loading without error now.  I am now starting to rearrange and re-title and test my functions with the form_set_messages to replace "$message"